# How to execute a command in the terminal from a Python script?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I want to execute a command in terminal from a Python script.

```
 ./driver.exe bondville.dat
```

This command is getting printed in the terminal, but it is failing to execute.

Here are my steps:

```
echo = "echo"
command="./driver.exe"+" "+"bondville.dat"
os.system(echo + " " + command)
```

It should execute the command, but it's just printing it on terminal. When feeding the same thing manually it's executing. How do I do this from a script?

Comment: Use the subprocess module

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am new to python, and this subprocess module seems very difficult for me to handle. How to use this ?

Comment: do you want to store the output or just run the command?

Comment: Remove the `echo` to actually run your commands. Now it just prints your `command` variable contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `echo` terminal command **echoes** its arguments, so printing the command to the terminal is the expected result.

Are you typing `echo driver.exe bondville.dat` and is it running your `driver.exe` program?
If not, then you need to get rid of the echo in the last line of your code:

```
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) module to run the command, you don't need to echo to run the command:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["./driver.exe", "bondville.dat"])
```

Which is equivalent to running `./driver.exe bondville.dat` from bash.

If you wanted to get the output you would use [check_outout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output(["./driver.exe", "bondville.dat"])
```

In your own code you are basically echoing the string `command` not actually running the command i.e `echo  "./driver.exe bondville.dat"` which would output `./driver.exe bondville.dat` in your shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("./driver.exe bondville.dat")
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are unhelpful since they don't tell what the problem was or how to fix it next time.